# How to convert varbinary(max) to base64 SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, base64, varbinarymax

I have an Image saved as `varbinary(max)` in SQL Server 2014:

> 0xFFD8FFE115064578696600004D4D002A0000000800070...........

I want to convert it to Base64 To use it in Flutter.
I tried

```
SELECT CAST('' as varbinary(max)) FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64
```

and get :

```
MHhGRkQ4RkZFMTE1MDY0NTc4Njk2NjAwMDA0RDREMDAyQTAwMDAwMDA4MDAwN..........
```

But according to this [site](https://www.base64-image.de/) I should get:

> /9j/4RUGRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAYgEbAA........

So how to convert `varbinary(max)` to base64?

Comment: `CAST('' as varbinary(max))` what are you casting? An empty string?

Comment: I think it depends on the image format, I just tried converting some of my images, and some come with your first format and some with the second. If you test your output [here](https://www.base64decode.net/base64-image-decoder) does it return an image?

Comment: What are you casting? If it's a varbinary(max) column as you say then why are you casting it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I *think* its to avoid having the resultant XML inside a tag - because that results in the column being unnamed, so no tag is added. Just a guess but its the same principle as when you use xml to string agg. Either way the query as shown actually works as intended - so issue is unreproducible.

Comment: Well then you `.value('.', 'varchar(max)')` the XML result to get the bare base64 characters. I think the OP is doing something other than they're telling us - otherwise why the `cast()`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sure, but many of the tutorials show this (cast) method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was Solved finally, I am not used to dealing with SQL or any APIs at all. and this project isn't mine I just want to finish it. So I copied first code I saw on the internet and try to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you attempting to `CAST()` the varbinary data? You just need to select it as an element or an attribute for the varbinary value to get base64 encoded...

```sql
/*
 * Data setup...
 */
if object_id('tempdb..#demo') is not null
  drop table #demo;
create table #demo (
  fancyImage varbinary(max)
);
insert #demo (fancyImage) values (0xFFD8FFE115064578696600004D4D002A000000080007);

/*
 * Select as an element containing base64 data
 */
select fancyImage as [base64DemoElement]
from #demo
for xml path(''), binary base64;

/*
 * Select as an attribute containing base64 data
 */
select fancyImage as [@base64Attribute]
from #demo
for xml path('demoElement'), binary base64;
```

The first select outputs the base data in an element:

```xml
<base64DemoElement>/9j/4RUGRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABw==</base64DemoElement>
```

The second select outputs the base64 data in an attribute:

```xml
<demoElement base64Attribute="/9j/4RUGRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABw==" />
```

Following comments discussion with @DaleK, a third alternative to return the bare base64 characters without any XML tags:

```sql
select (
  select top 1 cast(fancyImage as varbinary(max)) as [base64DemoElement]
  from #demo
  for xml path(''), type, binary base64
  ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as [Base64 characters];
```

Which outputs:

| Base64 characters |
| --- |
| /9j/4RUGRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABw== |

Comment: `.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)')` is slightly faster. Any case, you don't need to go so complicated, you can just use an unnamed column

Answer (score 2):

To select a bare Base64 value in SQL Server, without any XML node around it, you just need an unnamed column in `FOR XML`

```sql
SELECT CAST(fancyImage AS varbinary(max))
FROM #demo
FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64;
```

Or as a correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT
  myBase64 = (
    SELECT CAST(fancyImage AS varbinary(max))
    FOR XML PATH(''), BINARY BASE64
  )
FROM #demo;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=331517d708517af960cef1e489e62c40)

Answer (score 0):

I think it was v2008 of SQL-Server, when base64 was made the default in XML for binaries (before it was a hex string). No need to specify this explicitly.

(The option `BINARY BASE64` is needed with mode `AUTO`...)

Just to demonstrate the back and forth I declare some text (a chain of characters) and cast it to binary (the same chain of bytes, but not a string any more):

```
DECLARE @someText    VARCHAR(100)    = 'This is just some text...';
DECLARE @binary      VARBINARY(MAX)  = CAST(@someText AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

--In this case it's okay to rely on implicit casting: easy approach

```
DECLARE @base64_easy VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT @binary FOR XML PATH(''));
```

--Just to demonstrate that the base64 we found (`VGhpcyBpcyBqdXN0IHNvbWUgdGV4dC4uLg==`) is correct we reconvert it simply by casting it to `XML` and using `.value()` to retrieve it as `binary`:

```
DECLARE @reConverted VARBINARY(MAX) = (SELECT CAST(@base64_easy AS XML).value('.','varbinary(max)'));
```

--Casting this chain of bytes into a `varchar` again will show its (unchanged) content:

```
SELECT CAST(@reConverted AS VARCHAR(100));
```

All of this can be used within ad-hoc queries.

**Hint:**

The more explicit statement `SELECT`s the value into XML and reads this into text via `.value()`
(The `,type` is needed to allow for XML methods)

```
DECLARE @base64 VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT @binary FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'); --VGhpcyBpcyBqdXN0IHNvbWUgdGV4dC4uLg==
```